# is amcl required together with laser_scan_matcher for navigation?

Tags: ros, navigation, laser-scan-matcher, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It it required to run amcl together with laser_scan_matcher to achieve navigation ?

laser_scan_matcher already gives the pose, would it be possible then to launch move_base alone and set initial pose and 2D target in rviz ? I use the 2dnav_neato node that loads the map server, amcl, and move_base. So I thought I could remove amcl and leave only laser_scan_matcher...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57859/is-amcl-required-together-with-laser_scan_matcher-for-navigation-?/) by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik laser_scan_matcher is just a scan to scan matcher. That means it updates the pose based on the current scan and the previous scan(s).
AMCL on the other hand uses a map to perform localization (also it is a monte carlo approach and not just plain scan matching/registration).

scan to scan has the disadvantage that it will likely suffer from drift due to sensor noise, meaning you dont have fixed reference point for your nav goal as you don't have a map.

if the reason for you trying to avoid AMCL is that you dont want to map in beforehand, maybe try a setup with one of the SLAM frameworks available in ROS. I'd suggest gmapping or hector SLAM to do so.

But to answer your question, yes it is possible. One example that might help you could be the youbot navigation stack: http://youbot-store.com/libraries/19/software.aspx

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on 2013-03-12**:
I managed to make a good map with laser_scan_matcher and gmapping, but I'm having trouble doing navigation using the scan matcher with amcl and the existing map. my goal is trying to do navigation without odometry, but it doesn't work yet. I will look at your link, thanks.

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2016-05-21**:
haved you solved your problem? I used hector_slam to successfully build a map only with a laser scan. then, use laser_scan_matcher to fake the odometry for amcl from that laser scan and now, the amcl result is OK. But when I insert the move_base, problem occured:

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2016-05-21**:
63662615.549465621]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1463662615.5494, global_pose stamp: 1463080943.2246, tolerance: 2.0000
I have tried my best to solve, but still no ideas.If you have any good suggestions, I would be very grateful

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-11**:
@Tarantula-7 Im doing the same thing. But the laser _scan_matcher doesnt work. It says

```
Error in scan matching
Invalid number of rays: 36000
```

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2017-03-11**:
What device you used? I have tried Hokoyu UTM-30LX-EW and RPLIDAR A2, both all right

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-12**:
@Tarantula-7 Im using velodyne. Is your RPlidar 360 degree scan?

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2017-03-13**:
not sure it can be used in 3D LiDAR or not...